# Is it possible to alter nodes on export with Node Export

Tags: importing-exporting

I want to write my own module which changes a few things upon exporting of nodes with Node Export. 
I saw that there are some API's. But I haven't seen any working examples. Is there some documentation on the API of Node Export? And if not can someone provide me with some examples of changing data for export and changing it again upon import?

Thanks,
Jaap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the nodes in hook_node_export_node_alter() and hook_node_export_node_import_alter()
See [node_export.api.php](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/node_export/tree/node_export.api.php?h=7.x-3.x) for more information.

Comment: I have indeed used the hook_node_expert_alter and hook_node_export_node_import_alter and that works very well. Thanks